# Using ChartJs in Vue3 /not vue-chartjs/

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, vuejs3

### I know vue-chartjs is not supported in Vue3. So I decided to do it using ChartJs itself.

I have a form containing radio button and calendar and passing it to the chart component.
I couldn't write it in methods and I wrote it in `created`.
Because of this when I change the form inputs my chart is not reacting. I tried watching the values of prop coming from my form and it's reactive.

Help me

[image: here's the screenshot]
Here's my `TestGraph.vue` component

```
<template>
<div class="param-container">
    <h3>Params</h3>
    <p> {{radioCalendarUrl.frequency}}, {{radioCalendarUrl.from}}, {{radioCalendarUrl.to}} </p>
    <button @click="testMethod">Click</button>
</div>
<canvas id="test_chart" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 80%; height: 600px;"/>
</template>

<script>

import { ref, computed, defineComponent, onMounted} from "vue";
export default {
  name: 'Posts',
  data() {
    return{
    }
  },
  computed: {
    propsToUrl() {
      return '/?frequency='+`${this.radioCalendarUrl.frequency}`+'&from='+`${this.radioCalendarUrl.from}`+'&to='+`${this.radioCalendarUrl.to}`
    }
  },
  methods: {
    testMethod() {
      
      console.log(`${this.radioCalendarUrl.frequency}`)
      console.log(`${this.radioCalendarUrl.from}`)
      console.log(`${this.radioCalendarUrl.to}`)
      console.log(this.propsToUrl)
    },
  },
  watch: { 
    radioCalendarUrl: function(newVal, oldVal) { // watch it
      console.log('Prop changed: ', newVal, ' | was: ', oldVal)
    }
  },
  props: {
    radioCalendarUrl: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  async created() {
    const getData = (result) => {
      return [result.map(function(e) {
        return e.date;
      }),
      result.map(function(e) {
        return e.desktop;
      }),
      result.map(function(e) {
        return e.tablet;
      }),
      result.map(function(e) {
        return e.mobile;
      }),
      result.map(function(e) {
        return e.total;
      })]
    }
    let url1 = "http://localhost:8085/all-page-view" + this.propsToUrl
    const res1 = await fetch(url1)
    const result_pv = await res1.json()
    const res2 = await fetch("http://localhost:8085/uniq-user" + this.propsToUrl)
    const result_uu = await res2.json()
    
    console.log(url1)
    console.log("DATA")
    console.log(result_pv)
    const [xlabels, pc_pv_data, tablet_pv_data, smartphone_pv_data, total_pv_data] = [...getData(result_pv)]
    
    console.log([xlabels, pc_pv_data, tablet_pv_data, smartphone_pv_data, total_pv_data])
    const [xlabels_useless, pc_uu_data, tablet_uu_data, smartphone_uu_data, total_uu_data] = [...getData(result_uu)]
    
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    //function createChart(){
      var ctx = document.getElementById('test_chart');
          //グラフ詳細
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'bar',
          data: {
            datasets: [

              //ページビュー
              //PCページビュー
              {
                type: 'bar',
                label: 'PCページビュー',
                data: pc_pv_data,
                order: 5,
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(116,181,236)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(116,181,236)',
                barPercentage: 0.4
              },

              //タブレットページビュー
              {
                type: 'bar',
                label: 'タブレットページビュー',
                data: tablet_pv_data,
                order: 6,
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(244,192,121)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(244,192,121)',
                barPercentage: 0.4
              },

              // スマホページビュー
              {
                type: 'bar',
                label: 'スマホページビュー',
                data: smartphone_pv_data,
                order: 7,
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,191,227)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(255,191,227)',
                barPercentage: 0.4
              },

              //ページビュー合計
              {
                type: 'bar',
                label: 'ページビュー合計',
                data: total_pv_data,
                order: 8,
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(205,243,179)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(205,243,179)',
                barPercentage: 0.4
              },

              //UU
              //PCUU
              {
                type: 'line',
                label: 'PCUU',
                data: pc_uu_data,
                fill: false,
                order: 1,
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(59,128,186)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(59,128,186)',
                pointBorderWidth: 1,
                pointHoverRadius: 10,
                lineTension: 0,
                pointStyle: 'rectRot'
              },

              //タブレットUU
              {
                type: 'line',
                label: 'タブレットUU',
                data: tablet_uu_data,
                fill: false,
                order: 2,
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(247,129,42)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(247,129,42)',
                pointBorderWidth: 1,
                pointHoverRadius: 10,
                lineTension: 0,
                pointStyle: 'triangle'
              },

              //スマホUU
              {
                type: 'line',
                label: 'スマホUU',
                data: smartphone_uu_data,
                order: 3,
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(183,111,151)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(183,111,151)',
                fill: false,
                pointBorderWidth: 1,
                pointHoverRadius: 10,
                lineTension: 0,
                pointStyle: 'rect'
              },

              //UU合計
              {
                type: 'line',
                label: 'UU合計',
                data: total_uu_data,
                fill: false,
                order: 4,
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(142,177,110)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(142,177,110)',
                pointBorderWidth: 1,
                pointHoverRadius: 10,
                lineTension: 0,
                pointStyle: 'circle'
              }
            ],
            labels: xlabels
          },
          options: {
            responsive: false,
            legend: {
              position: 'bottom',
              labels: {
                fontColor: '#333',
                usePointStyle: true,
                fontSize: 12,
                boxWidth: 40,
              },
            },
            scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                scaleLabel: {
                  display: false,
                  labelString: 'ページビューとUU回数'
                },
                stacked: true,
                ticks: {
                  suggestedMin: 100,
                  callback: function(value) {
                    return value  + '回';
                  }
                }
              }],
              xAxes: [{
                stacked: true
              }],
            }
          }
      });
    //}
  },
  mounted() {
    
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: There's no reactive data bound to the chart anywhere. Are you expecting `radioCalendarUrl` to update the chart?

Comment: @tony19 I've found the solution!  just hud to bind the key `<TestChart :key="radioCalendarProps" :radioCalendarProps="radioCalendarProps"/>`

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution that worked for you.  However, the solution in your comment doesn't track with the example in your question (neither `TestChart` nor `radioCalendarProps` appear in your example code.